# Spring JPA query with only one argument case insensitive while having multiple arguments

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to write a spring boot query(with mongoDb) in the repository where I want one of the arguments needs to be **case insensitive** 
I can use something like this but then `personId` also becomes case insensitive and it does not allow the `Boolean` argument.

```
public Family findByNameAndPersonIdAndActiveIgnoreCase(String name, String personId, Boolean active);
```

A compound query or some annotation should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the `IgnoreCase` to only the property that need case insensitive

```
public Family findByNameIgnoreCaseAndPersonIdAndActive(String name, String personId, Boolean active);
```

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks ! Will leave it open for some time for a few more possibilities and select this as correct answer